# how to match multi email by regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a regular expression to match email, it works for one email, but for multi emails, it doesn't work. Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "my email are 670578362@qq.com and 178263745@163.com"
>>> r = re.search(r'[A-Za-z0-9\.+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+',str)
>>> print r.group()
670578362@qq.com # I want to get (670578362@qq.com, 178263745@163.com)
```

Comment: Exercise caution - email addresses and regular expressions are not good partners to put together. https://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-use-vs-regex-abuse/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re.search only finds the first occurrence.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

"Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern"

So this should do the trick:

```
import re
str = "my email are 670578362@qq.com and 178263745@163.com"
for r in re.finditer(r'[A-Za-z0-9\.+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+',str):
    print r.group()
```

Comment: `r = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z0-9\.+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+',str) ` will also work

Comment: that's actually more elegant and optimized

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to be a tuple instead of a list as you have in your question

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "my email are 670578362@qq.com and 178263745@163.com"
>>> r = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z0-9\.+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+',str)
>>> r = tuple(r) # ('670578362@qq.com', '178263745@163.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `findall` method of `re` which gives you list of group mathches
while `.group()` gives first match only

Hope this helps

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "my email are 670578362@qq.com and 178263745@163.com"
>>> r = re.findall(r'([A-Za-z0-9\.+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z0-9\.+_-]+)',str)
>>> r
['670578362@qq.com', '178263745@163.com']
```